# Send an applet from android device to pc

Tags: java, android, sockets, applet, serversocket

I am a newbie in android programming..
I am currently working on a project which is a Wi-Fi remote control. This app will send an applet from android phone to PC over Wi-Fi which is basically a media player applet, and the phone controls its features after the applet is installed on the web browser of pc. I want to know the process and the method/coding required to send this applet to pc over Wi-Fi.

Comment: It seems like you will need to run a web server on the android device and come up with an applet (and perhaps content) to serve.  Mostly what will be Android-unique will be the challenge of keeping it running - it can sort of be done, but Android is not designed/configured to be a server OS and so tends to shed background tasks in favor of foreground ones.  But if this is going to be something where someone generally has an associated app open on the screen while they are using this, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Yes.. That is what I want to do.. My phone will act as a server or you can say a wifi hotspot.. The applet will work as a client.. which will be loaded and run on the pc. This applet will then by controlled by my phone.

Comment: What I really want is just to send the applet just like some software like Kies Air does. It sends an applet to pc from android phone by wifi hotspot. The applet is accessed after accessing a certain IP address, and then the applet is sent. If this can be done, Please guide me about the methods and the coding and APIs required to do that.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not provide full solutions or package recommendations.  Rather, it is a place to get help with specific problems encountered in programs you are writing.  As mentioned above, at minimum you will need a web server on the phone, and the unspecified applet you wish to serve.  Our role is not to provide those or recommend them, but we can help with specific problems in developing them.